# Toggle slide div from hidden state

Tags: html, layer

From hidden state it doesn't work the If and else not working, what am I missing
I want the div layer #divbio to be hidden and then slide when clicked

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img").click(function(){
 if ( $('#divbio').slideToggle('visibility') == 'hidden' )
      $('#divbio').slideToggle('visibility','visible');
  else
  $('#divbio').slideToggle('visibility','hidden');
  });

  $("#divbio").slideToggle(500);
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<image onclick="Toggle slideUp() and slideDown();"><img src="images/image.gif" width="64" height="39" border="0" /></image> 
<div id="divbio" style="position:absolute; left:35px; top:119px; width:629px; height:792px; z-index:17; background-color: #000000; layer-background-color: #000000; border: 1px none #000000; background-image: url(Back.jpg); layer-background-image: url(Back.jpg); visibility: hidden;">
```

---

This works but is visible from load

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img").click(function(){
  $("#divbio").slideToggle(500);
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<image onclick="Toggle slideUp() and slideDown();"><img src="images/images.gif" width="64" height="39" border="0" /></image> 
<div id="divbio" style="position:absolute; left:35px; top:119px; width:629px; height:792px; z-index:17; background-color: #000000; layer-background-color: #000000; border: 1px none #000000; background-image: url(Back.jpg); layer-background-image: url(Back.jpg); visibility: hidden;"> 
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `visibility`, use `display`, as that's what `slideToggle()` modifies.

From the [`.slideToggle()` jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#entry-longdesc):

> The `display` property is saved and restored as needed. If
>   an element has a `display` value of `inline`,
>   then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed
>   `inline`. When the height reaches 0 after a hiding
>   animation, the `display` style property is set to
>   `none` to ensure that the element no longer affects the
>   layout of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***`display:none;`*** property instead of ***`visibility: hidden;`***, check this following

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xdp95/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        $('#divbio').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

`display:none;` property to when page load its display none but when you click on image slide toggle effect work. Hope this help you!